# How to install .exe on custom installation path using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, installation, windows-installer

By the batch script, I am installing a **.exe** but I do not want to install it in default path. I want to choose my custom Installation path. How can I change my file installation path in batch script?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Batch files can't interact with GUIs, so unless the installer for the program (that you haven't named) accepts command-line arguments, this can't be done.

Comment: I want to install Websphere Server7 using batch script.. but I want this in custom installation path. Is it possible to change the path in batch?

Comment: I can't find an option to specify the installation path via the installation script, but without a copy of the installer file, it's impossible for me to tell. You may want to ask this on SuperUser (while explicitly mentioning that this is to install Websphere Server V7 in a custom location).

Comment: you can do it using vbscript

Comment: Thanks amit..  Using vbscript, I have changed path.. :)